# If a function is derivable in a point then there exists an open interval around the point in which the function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $f:\ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is differentiable in $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove or give a counterexample:
There exists a $\delta \in \mathbb{R}_0^+$ as follows:

$$ \forall x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta):\ f \text{ is continuous in } x $$

I started by writing down what this means, but I got stuck immediately:

exists a $\delta \in \mathbb{R}_0^+$ as follows:

$$ \forall x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta):\ \forall y \in (a-\delta,a+\delta) \forall \epsilon \exists \eta: \forall z\in (a-\delta,a+\delta):\ |y-z|< \eta \Rightarrow |f(y)-f(z)|< \epsilon $$

Comment: Just asking: What's the "worst"/"most pathological" differentiable function you know of?

Comment: That's a very vague question.. I'm not sure.

Comment: I thought maybe you knew of a function that's differentiable at exactly one point. Anyway, you know of one now....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $$g(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x\notin\mathbb{Q}\\x^2,&x\in\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

We can compute $$g'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\begin{cases}0,&\text{ along the irrationals}\\\frac{x^2}{x},&\text{ along the rationals}\end{cases}=0$$

If $x\neq0$ there are arbitrarily close irrationals at which the function takes the value $0$ and rationals $y$ arbitrarily close $|x-y|<\delta<\left|\frac{x}{2}\right|$ (and in particular we use $x-\delta<y$ for $x>0$ or $y<x+\delta$ for $x<0$) at which the function takes the value $$y^2>(x\mp\delta)^2\geq x^2/4>0$$.

Therefore, the function is discontinuous at all points $x\neq0$.